# SImple http post using python

Tags: python, http

I have a quick question to call an `NLTK` Api using python.To find the sentiment of "great";
The API syntax is

```
 $ curl -d "text=great" http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/
```

I need to use a python request to post this and to receive a json object as response.I am trying to use with

```
resp = requests.post(url, data=values, allow_redirects=True)
```

if url is http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/
how must text parameter to be passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the guide from the requests [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/), to suit your requirement, this is what you do:

```
>>> import json
>>> url = 'http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/'
>>> payload = {'text': 'great'}

>>> r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Comment: The responce is retrieved as a json object.
    {
           "probability": {
                    "neg": 0.39680315784838732,
                    "neutral": 0.28207586364297021,
                    "pos": 0.60319684215161262
        },
        "label": "pos"
    }
How can i retrieve these parameters separately as neg pos neutral and label?

Comment: @AbhijathBenhur Isn't it what you want?

Comment: Yes this was exactly what i wanted.!! but i need to seperate the values of pos neg and neutral into seperate python variables.

Comment: Assuming whatever you pasted above is in a variable `json_response`, `neg = json_response['probability']['neg']` and similarly for pos and neutral. Please accept the answer if it resolves your issue :)

Comment: It results with a response of json_response not defined. :-( i have imported json

Comment: json_response is a variable name i came up with. Replace that with the variable in your code that contains the response.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49864/discussion-between-warunsl-and-abhijath-benhur)